# Timer that only runs during user input

Tags: bash, input, timer

Running Arch Linux

I have a script running that takes a screenshot every fifteen minutes, resizes it, and puts it in my dropbox folder.  This is kind of a pain when I leave my computer alone for a period of time and end up with multiple screenshots of the same thing.

What I'd like to do is take a screenshot after every fifteen minutes of USE, instead of every fifteen minutes.  I'd like to define USE as within 30 seconds of a keypress - if I sit and type for fifteen minutes, that counts.  If I just check on things once an hour all day, it only counts the time I'm actually typing.

How can I do this?  I'm open to any solution in any language, using any existing program, etc, as long as it works as described above (or close).

Comment: What's the greater context - i.e. why are you doing this? I just have a feeling that this is one of those things where you might get a better solution by looking at the bigger picture, maybe something that doesn't even involve detecting keypresses.

Comment: Could you take every screenshot, then compare it to the previous and drop it if it matches?

Answer (score 1):

The question David Z asks is worth answering; we can only speculate about your end goals, or reason for taking screen shots.  But that aside, following is a method that might help with the stated goal.  (This method is crude; I imagine a better solution could be suggested if I knew more about xscreensaver.)

To start, install and set up [xscreensaver](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/) (if using a screensaver is compatible with your habits; if not, see next answer).

As described in the xscreensaver [man page](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man3.html), add `xscreensaver-command -watch` in a `read` loop to your screenshot script.  Whenever a `LOCK` or `BLANK` occurs, save the amount of time T elapsed since previous screenshot and stop the timer.  When `UNBLANK` occurs, either reset the timer to 15-T, or perhaps take a screenshot and set the timer to 15.

You might instead just forego the current screenshot if the screen is blanked, and keep your 15-minute timer running on a regular schedule.  You could use `xscreensaver-command -time` to find out if a state change occurred since your previous screenshot.

A simpler way for your script to find out if the screen is blanked is shown below.

```
    xset -q | grep Monitor
```

will produce `Monitor is Off` if the screen is blanked, else `Monitor is On`.  Suppose your screen-saver monitor-off delay is K minutes and your script wakeup interval is L minutes.  Let W1, W2 denote two successive script wakeups. Suppose that at W1 xset said monitor on, and at W2 said it is off.  Then at W2 you know there has been no keyboard activity during the last K minutes.  However, the idle interval could have been as long as K+L minutes.  If you want to tighten the bounds, decrease K and L, or use a counter.  Here is a script that illustrates using a counter. To see the script in action, replace 3m with 1 and run it.  Then change 1 back to 3m and put your screen shot procedure in place of the `echo` in function ss.

```
#!/bin/bash

ss() {
    echo Taking snapshot at $(date)
}

busy=0
while true; do
    xset -q | grep -q "Monitor is On" && ((++busy > 4)) && busy=0 && ss
    sleep 3m
done
```

Comment: The greater picture is that I'm uploading screenshots to dropbox, and then IFTTT puts them on facebook (later on I could switch it to tumblr).  It's a voluntary monitoring thing I'm developing to help me limit the amount of time I spend on the computer and encourage me to be productive when I am using it.

Also, as far as the timer goes, I currently gues have a "sleep 15m" as part of a while while loop, so I don't know how to go about resetting.  Obviously I need a better timer setup.